# Register handler in autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-2.0, mediatr

Autofac and MediatR in use.
I'm trying to register handler in ContainerBuilder, but it is always error

> Cannot instantiate implementation type 'DataSourceHandler`2[TEntity,TModel]' for service type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler'2[DataSourceQuery'2[TEntity,TModel],Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult]'

My Query:

```
public class DataSourceQuery<TEntity, TModel> : IRequest<DataSourceResult>
        where TEntity : class, IEntityBase
        where TModel : class
    {
        public DataSourceRequest Request { get; set; }
    }
```

Handler:

```
public class DataSourceHandler<TEntity, TModel> : IRequestHandler<DataSourceQuery<TEntity, TModel>, DataSourceResult>
        where TEntity : class, IEntityBase
        where TModel : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;

        public DataSourceHandler(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public DataSourceResult Handle(DataSourceQuery<TEntity, TModel> message)
        {
            return context.Set<TEntity>()
                .ProjectTo<TModel>()
                .ToDataSourceResult(message.Request);
        }
    }
```

I`ve tried to register it in different ways like:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DataSourceHandler<,>)).As(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DataSourceHandler<,>)).As(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>))
            .InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DataSourceHandler<,>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(DataSourceHandler<,>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DataSourceHandler<,>))
            .As(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(DataSourceHandler<,>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));
```

but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: See the sample on how to register the mediatR with autofac: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Autofac/Program.cs

Comment: It is not work too. I register in Startup.cs: services.AddMediatR();

Answer (score 1):

The error message you posted seems to indicate that the `DataSourceHandler<TEntity, TModel>` type is correctly registered as `IRequestHandler<DataSourceQuery<TEntity, TModel>, DataSourceResult>`, since the message contains the name of the type.

It looks like it cannot be instantiated, though. Since the only dependency of this type is `ApplicationDbContext`, can you double check you registered that type in the container builder?